# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string' in Antd Select value?

Tags: typescript, antd

I have 2 selects, both with `mode="multiple"` and both being passed an array of strings as `value={query.x}`. But one is throwing a typescript error and the other isn't. And if I comment out the one not working, the page renders and everything is fine, so something fishy is going on.

[image]
[image]

Why is it giving me that `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'` error, only in one case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because my `onChange` handler still had `value: string` on it, instead of `value: Array<string>`!